# Asp.Net Xml must match 1 XSD

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd

I've been trying to find an answer to this question for some time:

[Having issue deserializing string with XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415017/having-issue-deserializing-string-with-xsd)

Here's an article which leads me to think the question above isn't answerable.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6280cbc-2a78-48c8-bfb7-27aff6c3fd04/xsd-element-conditionalcoconstraint-question?forum=xmlandnetfx

However, after more searching, I fear that what I want to do isn't achievable in the form, with VS + .Net 4 due to a lack of support form Xml 1.1 (I may be wrong!)

So I'm looking for other ways of acheiving what I need.

Here's the scenario:

I have an Xml file containing just 5 elements. The response can be one of 3 variations - accepted, declined or rejected - based on this status, certain other elements are required and/or restricted to certain values.

I could read the Xml to get the status then apply 1 of 3 other XSD's to validate the rest of the data but it does seem cumbersome.

Anyone know of a better way to validate my content, so it much match either A, B or C?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your earlier question is only 5 hours old.  (1) Don't give up on it so soon.  (2) If you have further thoughts on that question, especially since it's not received any answers yet, edit it -- don't post a new question that's nearly the same.  Thanks.

Comment: The reason, I asked a new question is because the first one asks specifically how to get the code working - in short, I'm now sure it's not possible. This question is different - I'm looking for alternative ways of achieving what I need, which is nothing to do with the solution I was experimenting with. By the way I haven't givem up - I've been searching for an answer all weekend and I believe after reading lots of articles, that it's not feasible - so I haven't given up - just taken it on the chin. Unfortunately, I have very little experience with Xml, so I can only rely on what I read.

Comment: To avoid needing XSD 1.1, don't use a `Status` element with values for declined, accepted, or rejected.  Instead, define `Declined`, `Accepted`, and `Rejected` as elements whose content models can vary.

Comment: @kjhughes - As I said, I'm not so hot on Xml, can you please explain a little more ot show a bit of sample code so that I can get the gist.

Comment: Someone else may have time for that if you're patient.  Let us know if you are open to such a restructuring away from your current `Status`-based scheme.

Comment: I'm open to any solution, but I can't change the incoming Xml as its from a third party.

Comment: If you cannot change the XML design, and you cannot use XSD 1.1, then you cannot be so strict about the content models.  Make the varying children all be optional, and let the content model be the union of the individual content models.

Comment: What do you mean by "content model"?

Comment: Please read about both [***content model***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-contentModel) and [ask].  **This excessive back-and-forth is a sign of that you've not asked your question properly.**  Good luck.